# CallableStatement doesn't recognize OUT parameter

Tags: java, mysql, callable-statement

I have an example of a stored procedure in MySql and I want to call it with JDBC. The problem is that I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 1 is not an OUT parameter
```

The stored procedure's definition is :

```
delimiter \\
create procedure get_average (
  out a decimal(8,2)
)
begin
  select avg(grade) into a from students;
end \\
```

As you can see I have a students table and I calculate the average. It works fine when I test in in MySql.

The java code :

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("call get_average(?)");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
double average = cstmt.getDouble(1);
```

where con is an opened Connection. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.DECIMAL);` already?

Comment: yes i tried it. the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call get_average(?)}");
```